# exe is not working where VS 2012 is not installed...

Tags: c#, wpf

i have created an exe which works only in those PC's where visual studio is installed.. not working where Visual studio is not installed ?

what is minimum requirement for an exe where visual studio is not installed ?

Comment: are you missing some library or dependency on the target machines?

Comment: tell to us the error details

Comment: This is off topic as not about programming. Before it gets closed understand this - When you install Visual Studio it installs .NET framework (if not pre-installed). If you don't have VS you at least need to assure that .NET framework is installed. VS is just an IDE that works with framework.

Comment: What about required .net version? Maybe you are missing newer .NET that is present with visual studio 2012.

Comment: Install .net frameworks on the target machines until it starts working.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a visual studio project, you target a specific framework version. You can check that by `Solution Explorer => Right Click Project => Application > Target Framework`.

This .NET framework needs to be installed on the PC for the application to work.

To run the generated EXE, you need the `CLR` to be installed which is shipped as part of the [.NET Framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=.net%20framework).